# List currently running cron tab and stop it

Tags: linux, cron

I created a cronjob, it runs for a very long time but now don't know how to stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop the process that the crontab started running.

```
#kill -HUP PID (PID: Process ID is the process running)
```

To see a relation of the PID with the running processes (and more info) use `top` command, change the column order with the keys `<` and `>`

Also try `ps -ax|grep [your_process_file]` which lists the running processes filtered by the name you choose

*-HUP* = Hang UP

Comment: I typed "top" but didn't see my cron in the list.

Comment: You shouldn't see `cron` or `crontab`, you are be looking for the process that you cron just run. By the way, if you edit your cron (`crontab -e`), erase the cronjob line and save, your process won't run again

Comment: I created a cron running update_user.php. When I typed "top", there is no process with name "update_user.php", I just see a list with "mysqld", "php", "init", ... How to know my cron's PID?

Comment: How was the cronjob call? was it something like `0 0 * * * /var/www/update_user.php`?

Comment: Yes! Something like this 50 3 1 * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/www/xxx/libs/update_user.php. I'm sure it started.

Comment: Then the process is named `php` and you should be careful to kill the right one!

Comment: ok, then try `ps ax|grep update_user.php` it usually displays the file associated to the process...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch He'll rather use `ps ax` better than blind killing processes...

Comment: @Nacho: I tried you shell, it shows
17043 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep update_user.php

Comment: That is only the `grep` call... you cannot kill it, because it's already finished. My guess is that your process has already died. Are you sure it's still running?

Comment: so how to know whether it is running?

Comment: What does your process do??? You are the only one knowing that... When the process ends, it disables from memory, thus from running... Crontab doesn't run processes forever unless you specify `* * * * *` which means "run the process once every minute`

Comment: your actual cronjob is configured `50 3 1 * *` which means "every 1st day of the month at 3:50 am"

Comment: It's just an example, not the currently running cron. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Then `ps fax`, `ps aux` or `top` will help you finding the PID next time. GL!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6759/discussion-between-nacho-and-emerald214)

Answer (score 4):

Shame that in this and other pages listed in google results on how ot deal with hung cron jobs that noone ever mentions pstree.

```
pstree
```

Look under cron part of the tree

Answer (score 3):

I think if a shell-script wrapper is around that should timeout the cronjob, if it is running for a lengthy arbitrarily enough long periods of time. The wrapper should send the SIGHUP or SIGALARM when the timeout happens from the period the cronjob is invoked.  Something like this:

```
50 * * * * /usr/bin/my_cron_wrapper_timeout -t 1 /usr/bin/my_command_cron_job_to_run
```

This cron_wrapper_timeout should basically send the timeout signal once -t switch option 1 hour passes and then should send `kill -HUP` signal to the cronjob and then make sure to reap the process as well and then end/kill itself.

Or alternatively, the code should be written with in the cronjob itself to handle the ALARM signal timeout and make sure it cleans up before it dies gently.

**EDIT**

This is exactly what I was referring to: watchdog at http://chihungchan.blogspot.com/2011/03/no-more-hanging-jobs-in-cron.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all check the working process with this command.

```
ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | egrep "( |/)cron( -f)?$"
```

This command's output is

```
599  599 cron
4288  599 \_ CRON
```

and now kill the process with this command

```
pkill -s 4288
```